# Limit characters to Letters and Numbers in input field

Tags: regex, forms, input

I want that people trying to subscribe on my website to enter a nickname and that nickname should exclusively consist of letters and numbers (no special characters at all).

I would like somthing as following : `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890`  only.

How can I check if it has only those?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The HTML5 solution would be...

```
<input type="text" id="input-nickname" name="nickname" pattern="[a-z\d]*"  />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DPzuT/).

However, for best browser support, you could use JavaScript...

```
document.getElementById('input-nickname').onkeyup = function(event) {

    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z\d]/, '');

}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/vv5hh/).

To make the JavaScript version similar to the HTML5 method, look at the form's `submit` event.

Keep in mind this has a pretty strict definition of letters and numbers. For proper Unicode support, find the ranges you care about and use `\u0000-\uFFFF` to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look at: [RegEx library](http://www.regxlib.com/Search.aspx?k=string&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20)

It contains a lot of RegEx that you can test directly on the site and change according to your needs.

I always use it as source whenever I need to work with RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple solution **for React users only** (the above solution doesn't work properly in React). 3 steps.

First, create a state.

```
const [tagInputVal, setTagInputVal] = useState("");
```

Then, use the state as input value (`value={tagInputVal}`) and pass the event to the `onChange` handler.

```
<input id="tag-input" type="text" placeholder="Add a tag" value={tagInputVal} onChange={(e) => onChangeTagInput(e)}></input>
```

Then, set the value of the event inside `onChange` handler.

```
function onChangeTagInput(e) {
    setTagInputVal(e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d]/ig, ""));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

with javasacript

```
function testAlphanumeric(input){
var regex=/^[0-9A-Za-z]+$/;
if(regex.test(input)){
alert("Good")
return true;
} else {
alert("Incorrect")
return false;
}
}
```

source link: 
http://newsourcemedia.com/blog/javascript-non-alphanumeric-characters-regex/

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The javascript version from alex looks very very cool. But I tried to push multiple letters at once and when I release keys it would not delete all special characters. I just want a function (php is fine) that check either true or false the string contains other characters than a-z 0-9

Comment: I will be using somthing like if (preg_match("REGEX", "string to check"))