# Javascript string replace on non numeric and letter s

Tags: javascript

```
var value = document.getElementById("height_"+ rowCount).value;
value = value .replace("a", "");
document.getElementById("height_"+rowCount).value = value;
```

Above is a javascript example that I used to replace the letter "a" in my text field height_row e.g height_1 (for row 1)

I want to able to filter all input except

0 to 9, letter s, 
how do I auto replace all input with blank if its not number 0 to 9 or letter "s"

**Thanks for helping**

Comment: Look into [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
var rowCount = 1;

var value = document.getElementById("height_"+ rowCount).value;
value = value.replace(/[^0-9s]/g, "");
document.getElementById("height_"+rowCount).value = value;
```

```html
<input type="text" value="one 1 two 2 three 3 numbers" id="height_1" />
```

Comment: How do we modify the code such that when the textfield will replace all the char that doesn't match the "pattern" instantly after a letter is type

Comment: That's a different question. See, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763012/limit-characters-to-letters-and-numbers-in-input-field